# facebook login ask password

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app and I am building a facebook integration. I am basically creating a user in my web app based on the information facebook sends. All I really need is the name and the e-mail, which I have got already.

My question is - it's more of a logic issue. I am not too familiar with facebook, I don't use it... but a lot of my users do.

After the user accepts the permissions and returns from facebook, I have a little "mini user signup" where they can, optionally, answer a couple more questions about themselves. At this point, should I offer them to also create a password, if they want to log in traditionally? or should I skip the whole password thing?

Also what is the feeling as to asking a couple more questions to complete the user?

Thanks